# Align texts with the formula

Tags: pdftex, alignment, xymatrix

I'm using the package xymatrix to create the following diagram:

[image]
The diagram is bigger than the text, **but the texts don't automatically go to the center of the line.**

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Let $F:I\to\mathcal C$ be a functor, the diagram 
$\xymatrix@C=1em{
F(i)\ar[rr]^{F(f)}\ar[rd]_{p_i} && F(j) \ar[dl]^{p_j}
\\
& c
}$ commutes.


\end{document}
```

What I want is this:

[image]

**Notice how the texts go to the center of the line in the 2nd picture.** How can I accomplish this? Thank you so much.

Comment: I would rephrase your Definition so, that commutative diagram will be moved out of text and displayed below text. Much nicer, at least to my taste. Otherwise, you need to move diagram baseline to its vertical center. To show, how to do this, you first should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko There are lots of diagrams in this note, so fully displaying the diagrams would cost too much space. Is there any way to move the text to the center of the line?

Comment: A simple approach would probably be to use `\raisebox`.

Comment: I ask for MWE, a complete small document, not only for code fragment. We need to know, which document class you use and which are relevant packages loaded in preamble. MWE we like to compile as it is. Inserting diagrams into text is bad praxis, but anyway in my previous comment I told you how can you do.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry for the confusion. I have added the complete MWE. I can't fully display the diagrams because they cost too much space. Could you suggest another approach?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Could you specify how to use `\raisebox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the vertical centering depends on the height of the concrete diagram, it is better to use `\vcenter` than `\raise box`.

The usage of `\vcenter` is:

```
...text $\vcenter{\hbox{$...diagram...$}}$ text...
```

in your example:

```
Let $F:I\to\mathcal C$ be a functor, the diagram 
$\vcenter{\hbox{$\xymatrix@C=1em{
F(i)\ar[rr]^{F(f)}\ar[rd]_{p_i} && F(j) \ar[dl]^{p_j}
\\
& c
}$}}$ commutes.
```

You can define the `\cdiagram` macro

```
\def\cdiagram#1{$\vcenter{\hbox{$#1$}}$}
```

and then use it:

```
Let $HF:I\to\mathcal C$ be a functor, the diagram 
\cdiagram{\xymatrix@C=1em{
F(i)\ar[rr]^{F(f)}\ar[rd]_{p_i} && F(j) \ar[dl]^{p_j}
\\
& c
}} commutes.
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Jasper Habicht suggest in his comment, you can use `\raisebox` as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Let $F:I\to\mathcal C$ be a functor, the diagram \raisebox{1.5em}{$\xymatrix@C=1em{
F(i)\ar[rr]^{F(f)}\ar[rd]_{p_i} && F(j) \ar[dl]^{p_j}
\\
& c
}$} commutes.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I really doubt that any publisher will accept so formatted article.

**Addendum:**
A possible solution can be use of `wrapfig` package ...

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} % <--- push image to top of paragraph
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,
            skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\input xy
\xyoption{all}


\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[6]{r}{8em}% explicit reserved space for wrapfigure
    \centering\vspace*{-1ex}
$\xymatrix@C=1em{F(i)\ar[rr]^{F(f)}\ar[rd]_{p_i}    && F(j) \ar[dl]^{p_j}  \\
                                                    & c}$    
\caption{}
\label{wrapfig:1}
    \end{wrapfigure}
Let $F:I\to\mathcal C$ be a functor. A cone (under) $F$ is an object $c\in i:F(i)\to c$, one for each object $i$ of $I$, such that for any two objects $i,j\in I$ and morphism $i\xrightarrow{f}j$ of $I$, the diagram commutes, see fig. \ref{wrapfig:1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]